# Is rated current supposed to vary based on voltage?

Tags: voltage, current, datasheet, maximum-ratings

Recently I have been reading a lot of datasheets and noticed that many manufacturers specify a current rating for their products (especially connectors) without specifying at what voltage the current rating applies (except for a max voltage).  This seems super counter intuitive for me as when the voltage increases you will have more power (watts) moving through the component that, in my mind, should affect the rated current.  So at a lower voltage you should be able to pass more than the rated current.

Some examples of this:

- https://www.molex.com/webdocs/datasheets/pdf/en-us/0475070010_PCB_HEADERS.pdf
- https://www.vishay.com/docs/31017/rcwp99.pdf (this one specifies a rated power but that is just for the voltage drop across the jumper.  What is the rated voltage at that current?)
- https://www.hirose.com/product/en/download_file/key_name/FH34SRJ-10S-0.5SH%2850%29/category/Specification%20Sheet/doc_file_id/43118/?file_category_id=9&item_id=05801251550&is_series=

These datasheets make it seem as if there is a physical property that attenuates current flow no matter the voltage when I think it is based on voltage and current.

Comment: The voltage between two pins has no effect whatsoever on the maximum current in a single pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects to the maximum allowable voltage specification a given resistor has.  One is the packages' power dissipation rating, which for a given value of resistance will have a maximum applicable voltage before heat dissipation values are exceeded: P=V^2/R

The second is a safety persective because the smaller the package the closer together the two terminals are.  Eventually the electric field gradient between them becomes so strong that you can get electromigration effects, tracking, etc. that will cause a short across the terminals.  There is a corollary in that post manufacture cleaning of boards becomes more critical as well, debris tends to become conductive over time with some soldering techniques.

In the case of the jumpers, Vishay RCCe3 series does have the voltage rating, could be the other datasheet is just missing the row (typos in datasheets happen all the time, most get caught some don't.)

Answer (score 1):

The current rating for connector contacts (and relay and switch contacts) is dependent on current, as current will cause heating of the contacts - this is independent of the applied voltage.

Voltage rating for a connector is based on the insulation and spacing between contacts, and does not depend on the current.

Comment: Note that the voltage (and sometimes current) rating also varies if the connectors or switches are to be operated under load, and especially if the supply is DC or the load is reactive. It is common to see switches and relays rated for 10A @ 250V AC, but only 30V DC due to the arc being much harder to extinguish in the DC case. For connectors mated or unmated under load (not all are designed to survive this) similar deratings can apply, check the datasheet small print.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I am just confused.  Thinking back to USB fast charging, the current in the wire is what you are trying to avoid by increasing the voltage.  By increasing the voltage (im pretty sure) you don't change much.  But by increasing the current you have a larger voltage drop across the conductor with V = I * R.  So to charge at high currents fast chargers send higher voltage lower current power and then the device will step the voltage down to something that the battery can accept.

Comment: Right. The current in the conductor is what leads to voltage drop and power loss (and consequent heating).